# How to write list of multilevel dictionaries into csv

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries stored in tweets, and I am trying to write these into a csv file using `writerows` method.

Sample List looks something like this:

```
[{'sentiment': 'Unknown', 'date': datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 5, 31, 32), 'body': 'mcd brk b'},
 {'sentiment': 'Unknown', 'date': datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 6, 55, 23), 'body': 'co hihq'},
 {'sentiment': {'basic': 'Bullish'}, 'date': datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 7, 36, 32), 'body': 'new year bac'}]
```

Here `sentiment` key has either one level or two. I am trying to write these dictionaries into a csv format such that I only have the values of these keys for above either 'Unknown' or 'Bullish'.

```
file = open('BAC.csv','w')
keys=tweets[0].keys()
dict_writer=csv.DictWriter(file,keys)
dict_writer.writerows(tweets)
```

I get the csv file in the following format

```
Unknown,2013-01-01 05:31:32,mcd brk b
Unknown,2013-01-01 06:55:23,co hihq
{'basic': 'Bullish'},2013-01-01 07:36:32,mnew year bac
```

But I need it as

```
Unknown,2013-01-01 05:31:32,mcd brk b
Unknown,2013-01-01 06:55:23,co hihq
Bullish,2013-01-01 07:36:32,mnew year bac
```

Is there any easy way to do this? In many instances the levels go up to five, but similar deal just need the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write a function to flatten these sentiment values.

Something like this could work if you have only one element in each level.

```
def flatten(row, field):
    if isinstance(row[field], dict):
        row[field] = row[field].values()[0]
        return flatten(row, field)
    return row
```

Then you would need to call this method on each row before writing it to the csv.

```
tweets = [{'sentiment': 'Unknown', 'date': datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 5, 31, 32), 'body': 'mcd brk b'},
         {'sentiment': 'Unknown', 'date': datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 6, 55, 23), 'body': 'co hihq'},
         {'sentiment': {'basic': {'text': 'Bullish' } }, 'date': datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 7, 36, 32), 'body': 'new year bac'}]

print [flatten(row, 'sentiment') for row in tweets]
```

Output

```
[{'date': datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 5, 31, 32), 'body': 'mcd brk b', 'sentiment': 'Unknown'},
 {'date': datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 6, 55, 23), 'body': 'co hihq', 'sentiment': 'Unknown'},
 {'date': datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 7, 36, 32), 'body': 'new year bac', 'sentiment': 'Bullish'}]
```